# angular protractor no element found using locator

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am using protractor locator below and

```
element(by.css('.config1100 .btn btn-default btn-lg')).click();
```

getting following error

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".config1100 .btn btn-default btn-lg")
```

html is templateURL of anuglar-ui view

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="config1100" ng-include="'../data/config1100.html'"></div>
    <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Each class name in the selector should be specified with dot in front `element(by.css('.config1100 .btn .btn-default .btn-lg')).click()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be simpler to use by.buttonText

```
element(by.buttonText('Save')).click();
```

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.buttonText

If you have more than one button with that text, grab the collection with element.all and figure out which one you need.

Answer (score 2):

You were missing a dot, so using the dollar shortcut notation:

```
$('.config1100 .btn .btn-default .btn-lg')).click();
```